# Angularjs 'in' filter in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My select box is in ng-repeat as,

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:filter">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="project.roleIds" ng-options= "role.id as role.name for role in roleList " multiple></select>
    </td>
<td>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="project.company" ng-options= "obj.id as obj.name for obj in compnayList | filter:{roleId:project.roleIds}"></select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

My roleId selection is multiple so I want to filter the company list dropdown on selection of the roles . so if I select two roles then company having anyone of the role will be there in the dropdown .
Now if I select only one role then it is filtered by it but not for multiple role. Can I do such in ng-options by angular filter . Custom filter will work ?

```
$scope.companyList=[{
    id:1,
    name:"ABC",
    roleId:1
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"ABCd",
    roleId:2
},
{
    id:3,
    name:"ABCgh",
    roleId:1
}];


$scope.roleList=[{
    id:1,
    name:"Grade A",
},
{
    id:2,
    name:"Grade B",
},
{
    id:3,
    name:"Grade C",
}];
```

And Project list is something like this,

```
$scope.projects=[{
    id:100,
    projectName:"Project 1", 
    roleIds: [1,2],
    company:1
},
....
];
```

Comment: can you show rolelist array? or you can create plunker for same

Comment: I have added roleList and projects array

Answer (score 0):

check here how you can use filter http://dojo.telerik.com/EmoQu

```
 <input type='text' ng-model='roleId' placeholder='role id'>
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="project.available" ng-options= 'obj.id as obj.name for obj in [{id:1,name:"ABC",roleId:1},     {id:2,name:"ABCd",roleId:2},{id:3,name:"ABCgh",roleId:1}] | filter:roleId'
```

> 

Considering your projects array is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use [comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
$scope.in = function (items, value) {
    return items.indexOf(value) !== -1;
};
```

In html:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="project.available"
ng-options="obj.id as obj.name for obj in compnayList | filter:{roleId:project.roleIds}:in">
</select>
```